# Unable to install ipfs

Tags: go

I'm trying to download ipfs on ubuntu so I can use it with golang.

I'm using the following command:

```
go get -d github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs
```

But that gives me the following error message:

```
package github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs
    imports runtime: cannot find package "runtime" in any of:
    /home/userone/go/src/runtime (from $GOROOT)
    /home/userone/gostuff/src/runtime (from $GOPATH)
```

I have added the following lines at the end of the file `~/.bashrc`

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed golang using the following command

```
sudo aptitude install golang-go git
```

Why am I getting that error message?

Comment: Don't set GOROOT.

Comment: What does your `go env` show with regard to `GOROOT` variable? Judging from your setting of the `PATH` env. variable you messed with the `GOROOT`--supposedly setting it to the same value your `GOPATH` has. That's plain wrong: since aeons ago, the `go` tool has the correct idea about the value of `GOROOT` automagically.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `$GOROOT/bin` in your `PATH` either: if you want to call any Go's inernal binary directly, the way to do that is to use `go tool <toolname>`: run `go tool` w/o arguments to see the list of what's available.

Answer (score 1):

Install instructions can be found at the README.md https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs#install

To compile from source, do:

```
  $ go get -u -d github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs

  $ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs
  $ make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make everything clear. Following are the only things you need to do( don't set GOROOT)

1. Set environment

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
>  export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

2. Install IPFS from source

> ```
> $ go get -u -d github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs
>
> $ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs<br>
> $ make install
> ```